# Keeping height of a flex item when varying height of items on the same row with align-item: stretch

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I use Bootstrap 4.4.1 and Jquery 3.4.1.

I have a list of flex items wrapping around a flex container defined by :

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}
```

Every flex item has the `.tile-rtiers` css class and has a variable height

```
.tile-rtiers {
  border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px 20px;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Those flex item are cards that have a collapsible `list-group` from Bootstrap inside them. This list has a variable number of item.

```
<div class="tile-rtiers">
                <div class="info-rtiers">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-item-1-0" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-item-1" id="collapse-pa-1-0" class="gras cursor-hover list-group-item">
                            LIST 3                  <p id="collapse-item-1-0" class="collapse">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod placerat ultricies. Integer at sem interdum, eleifend tellus a, viverra velit. Vivamus ultrices efficitur tempus. Duis placerat condimentum enim, ac condimentum nisl cursus faucibus. Donec pretium lectus in pellentesque convallis. Donec interdum nisi vitae mollis porta. Nunc maximus lacinia felis at auctor. Vivamus eleifend porttitor tortor ut molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin quis posuere risus. Praesent id dolor diam. 
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-item-1-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-item-1" id="collapse-pa-1-1" class="gras cursor-hover list-group-item">
                            LIST 4                  <p id="collapse-item-1-1" class="collapse">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod placerat ultricies. Integer at sem interdum, eleifend tellus a, viverra velit. Vivamus ultrices efficitur tempus. Duis placerat condimentum enim, ac condimentum nisl cursus faucibus. Donec pretium lectus in pellentesque convallis. Donec interdum nisi vitae mollis porta. Nunc maximus lacinia felis at auctor. Vivamus eleifend porttitor tortor ut molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin quis posuere risus. Praesent id dolor diam. 
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-item-1-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-item-1" id="collapse-pa-1-2" class="gras cursor-hover list-group-item collapsed">
                            LIST 5                  <p id="collapse-item-1-2" class="collapse" style="">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam euismod placerat ultricies. Integer at sem interdum, eleifend tellus a, viverra velit. Vivamus ultrices efficitur tempus. Duis placerat condimentum enim, ac condimentum nisl cursus faucibus. Donec pretium lectus in pellentesque convallis. Donec interdum nisi vitae mollis porta. Nunc maximus lacinia felis at auctor. Vivamus eleifend porttitor tortor ut molestie. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Proin quis posuere risus. Praesent id dolor diam. 
                            </p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My problem is that when I am expanding items, the flex item that's expanding makes his height vary. So every other elements on the same row stretch aswell because of the `align-items: stretch` property. 
I would like them to keep their own height while having the `align-items: stretch` look when nothing is expanded (the elements have the height of the tallest element of the row).

I have tried to set `align-self: stretch` to the flex items but the result is still the same.

Here's a codepen snippet of the problem
https://codepen.io/Idaan/pen/jObOBqb

Thank you

Comment: Hi, have you resolved it? I have the same issue, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I switched to another design that was fitting aswell for my need. But If someone, one day, find an answer, I'd be happy to test it out.